Timer not working in Blazor Web Application
I have simple Blazor Web Application (Server Side, .NET 8, VS2022).
Here main page:
@page "/"
@using System.Timers
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<p>@StatusMessage</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="StartHandler">Start</button>

@code {
    private void StartHandler()
    {
        Countdown = 100;
        timerCounter.Interval = 1000;
        timerCounter.Elapsed += TimerCounter_Elapsed;
        timerCounter.AutoReset = true;
        timerCounter.Start();
    }
    private void TimerCounter_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {        
        Countdown--;
        StatusMessage = $"{Countdown}";
    }

    private Timer timerCounter = new Timer();
    private int Countdown = 0;    
    private string StatusMessage = "";
}


It should start the timer on button click and show countdown on the page.
But when I click the button nothing happened.
On next clicks it shows count like 99 or 97.
I don't understand what is going.
Why the timer event doesn't fire?
Thanks.
I tried countdown on button's click and it works.
But I need the timer fires event.
Here is my App.razor file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


Add StateHasChanged. From the documentation: "Notifies the component that its state has changed. When applicable, this will cause the component to be re-rendered."
private void TimerCounter_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{        
    Countdown--;
    StatusMessage = $"{Countdown}";
    StateHasChanged();        
}


I got InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.

I've just tested it here and works fine: https://blazorfiddle.com/

I set it await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) and now it works.

As stated in the other answer, the solution is to add a call to StateHasChanged to the callback method.
The reason is callbacks aren't UI events.  There's no automatic call to StateHasChanged so you must add one manually.
StateHasChanged must run on the UI thread [the Synchronisation Context].
The timer process [running on it's own thread] schedules TimerCounter_Elapsed to run on the threadpool.  Invoking StateHasChanged through the component's InvokeAsync method switches execution to the UI thread.
private void TimerCounter_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{        
    Countdown--;
    StatusMessage = $"{Countdown}";
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);        
}

